# I'm a beginner in Python, just wanted to know what is the difference between putting a variable before a function and inside a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

what is the difference between?

```
var=0 
def abc():
```

and

```
def abc():
    var=0
```

I am fairly new to this world how ever I was always passionate towards CS.

Answer (score 2):

if you put your `var` outside of the function will be visible everywhere on your cod,  if you put under your function, your `var` will be visible only in the function and when you use that function

```
var1 = 10
def sum1(x):
    return x + var1 # var1 is global so can be accessed from other functions

def sum2(x):
    var2 = 12
    return x + var2 # var2 can be only accessed from sum2 function

def sum3(x):
    return var2 + x 

print(sum1(10))
print(sum2(10))
print(sum3(10))
```

output:

```
20
22
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-233-278acebe9c9f> in <module>
     12 print(sum1(10))
     13 print(sum2(10))
---> 14 print(sum3(10))

<ipython-input-233-278acebe9c9f> in sum3(x)
      8 
      9 def sum3(x):
---> 10     return var2 + x
     11 
     12 print(sum1(10))

NameError: name 'var2' is not defined
```

as you can see `sum3` it throw `NameError: name 'var2' is not defined` because `var2` it is visible only from `sum2` function